# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-a_n} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(a_n)^i}{i!}\right)$ converge if $(a_n) \subset [0,\infty)$ is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n) \subset [0,\infty)$ be bounded. Does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-a_n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(a_n)^i}{i!}\right)$$
>   converge?

I tried rewriting and different things but didn't come to a conclusion.

What I tried:

Let $S_N$ be the $N$'th partial sum of the given series. We have

$$ S_N \leq  \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(e^{a_n} - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(a_n)^i}{i!}\right). $$

So the question is how fast the inner sum converges to $e^{a_n}$. I guess it's fast enough but I couldn't find a way to show it.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope.

Comment: Ok, better now? @robjohn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $n$, let $X_n$ denote some random variable with [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) of parameter $a_n$, then the sum under consideration is $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-P(X_n\leqslant n-1))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n\geqslant n)$$
One further assumes that $(a_n)$ is bounded, say, for every $n$,

> $$a_n\leqslant a$$

Then every $X_n$ is [dominated in distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering) by a random variable $X$ with Poisson distribution of parameter $a$, in particular, $$P(X_n\geqslant n)\leqslant P(X\geqslant n)$$ This yields

> $$S\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\geqslant n)=E(X)=a$$

In particular, $S$ is finite.

---

Now that probability theory showed the way to a proof, one can, if one wants to, concoct an approach that avoids using explicitely probabilistic notions. Namely, one might want to show that every function $$s_n(x)=e^{-x}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}$$ is nonincreasing on $x\geqslant0$ because $$s'_n(x)=-e^{-x}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\leqslant0$$
hence $$s_n(a_n)\geqslant s_n(a)$$ and $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-s_n(a_n))\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-s_n(a))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{i=n}^\infty e^{-a}\frac{a^i}{i!}=e^{-a}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a^i}{i!}\sum_{n=1}^i1=e^{-a}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a^i}{i!}i=\ldots$$ which can be completed easily. Basically, what the proof we presented above accomplishes is to *explain* each step in this sequence of (otherwise, rather opaque) computations.

Comment: Is the step with dominance so trivial that it does not need any justification? I could just figure it out intuitively through the link with the poisson process and the exponential distribution. I mean that I could not see it just from the fact that $a_n\leq a$. (+1) from me for the probabilistic approach !

Comment: @Shashi Yes. To a probabilist, the domination of $Y_\lambda$ Poisson of parameter $\lambda$ by $Y_\mu$ Poisson of parameter $\mu$ if $\mu>\lambda$, is direct, for example because, then, $$Y_\mu=^dY_\lambda+Y$$ where $Y$ is Poisson of parameter $\mu-\lambda$ and independent of $Y_\lambda$.

Comment: good!! I already thought something simple was going on! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm... Lovely downvote (MSE true to its reputation, or what?).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $0\le a_n\le A$. For $n\ge2A-1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,e^{a_n}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_n^k}{k!}\,\right|
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{a_n^k}{k!}\\
&\le\frac{a_n^n}{n!}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac{a_n}{n+1}\right)^{k-n}\\
&=\frac{a_n^n}{n!}\frac{n+1}{n+1-a_n}\\[6pt]
&\le2\frac{A^n}{n!}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Short, nice, clear. (+1)

Comment: Note that $a_n\in[0,\infty)$ is bounded.